# Grep into given filenames

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe

I have a directory that contains many subdirectories that contain many files.

I list the contents of the current directory using `ls *`. I see that there are certain files that are relevant, in terms of their names. Therefore, the relevant files can be obtained as such `ls * | grep "abc\|def\|ghi"`.

Now I want to search within the given filenames. So I try something like:
`ls * | grep "abc\|def\|ghi" | zgrep -i "ERROR" *`, however, this is not looking into the file contents, rather the names. Is there an easy way to do this with pipes?

Comment: You an try to do it with (using your example):
`zgrep -i "ERROR" $(ls * | grep "abc\|def\|ghi")`

Comment: Don't use `ls` for finding files.  Use `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use grep to search the contents of files within a directory, try using the `find` command, using `xargs` to couple it with the grep command, like so:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep '...'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
find -E . -type f -regex ".*/.*(abc|def).*" -exec grep -H ERROR {} \+
```

The `-E` allows use of extended regexes so you can use the pipe (`|`) for expressing alternations. The `+` at the end allows searching in as many files as possible for each invocation of `-exec grep` rather than needing a whole new process for every single file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use xargs to grep each file contents:

```
ls * | grep "abc\|def\|ghi" | xargs zgrep -i "ERROR" *
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a solution with pipes, but they are not necessary for this task. `grep` has many parameters, and can solve this problem alone:

```
grep . -rh --include "*abc*" --include "*def*" -e "ERROR"
```

Parameters:

```
--include : Search only files whose base name matches the give wildcard pattern (not regex!)
-h : Suppress  the  prefixing  of file names on output.
-r : recursive
-e : regex filter pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -i "ERROR" `ls * | grep "abc\|def\|ghi"`
```